# Tomcat 7 - mysql driver cannot be found

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat

I want to setup MySql as a data source for Tomcat so it can be used with Spring. I have defined the data source in Tomcat's context.xml and added MySQl connector jar to Tomcat's libs

```
ls /opt/tomcat/tomcat/lib/ | grep mysql
mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
```

Here is  **$TOMCAT/conf/context.xml**:

```
<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

 <Resource name="jdbc/mysqldb"
     auth="Container"
     type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     username="my-user"
     password="my-password"
     driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/organizer"
     maxActive="8"
     maxIdle="4"/>

</Context>
```

and here is the relevant part of **springContext.xml** although I doubt it matters in this case.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="/jdbc/mysqldb"
    resource-ref="true" />
```

But still I get this exception:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/organizer'
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at my.pckg.organizer.MySpringContextListener.contextInitialized(MySpringContextListener.java:14) [MySpringContextListener.class:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.59]
        ... 44 common frames omitted
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you need two slashes before the host name, like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/...`?

Comment: Unbelievable but you are so right! I have checked the driver class name 100 time but I never checked the URL.  Do you think this could be an improper exception message worth of minor bug report?

Comment: Hard to see how it's a bug. Your URL was taken as `scheme=jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/organizer host= port= database=`, so it looked for a driver for `mysq:/localhost:3306/organizer.` That's what you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes your **$TOMCAT/conf/context.xml:** to

```
<Context>

<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<Resource name="jdbc/mysqldb"
   auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   username="my-user"
   password="my-password"
   driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/organizer"
   maxActive="8"
   maxIdle="4"/>

</Context>
```

You have missed to add "/" in url.